# If there are validation errors show the errors in the view (using ajax post request)

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a multi step form. In the step 1 the user needs to inser info like his name, surname, etc. When the user click in "go to step 2" is send an ajax post request to the controller method storeUserInfo to validate the information introduced by the user.

Do you know, if there are validation errors how to show the errors in the view (above the step1 form)?

I have a errors.blade.php file with the content below. In forms where i dont use ajax, to show the validation errors I just use "                  `@include('includes.errors')`". But with ajax is not working like that. Errors.blade.php:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

**PaymentController method: I have the buyer_name with max 1 just to test the validation**

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        //dd($request);
        $request->validate([
            'buyer_name' => 'required|max:1|string',
            'buyer_surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'buyer_email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'name_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'country_invoice' => 'required|max:100|string',
        ]);
        return redirect(route('products.presentPaymentMethods',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));

    }
```

**Route for the post request:**

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/storeUserInfo', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeUserInfo',
    'as'   =>'products.storeUserInfo'
]);
```

**step1 html:**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <h6>User Info</h6>
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
        </div>
        <!-- other form fields -->
        <input type="submit" id="goToStep2" href="#step2"
                class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var page_form_id = "step1form";

$('#goToStep2').on('click', function () {
    var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);
    var custom_params = custom_form.serializeArray();
    var custom_formData = new FormData();

    $(custom_params).each(function (custom_index, custom_element) {
        custom_formData.append(custom_element.name, custom_element.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '{{ route('products.storeUserInfo',null) }}',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: custom_formData,

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }, 3000);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            $.each(errors['message'], function (index, value) {

            });
        }
    });

    });
});
```

Comment: What does the error data look like coming from the ajax? You probably just need to loop through them and insert them into the relevant elements on the page. have you tried anything?

Comment: alert(errors) or console.log(errors)  dont shows nothing in: error: function (data) {
                        var errors = data.responseJSON;
                        console.log(errors);
                        $.each(errors['message'], function (index, value) {
                        });
                    }, even when is inserted a buyer name with more than 1 letter, that should result in a validation error just for testing purposes.

Comment: Is there any kind of text in the response, even if it's not JSON? You can check via responseText. P.S. Why are you bothering with ajax here? In the success condition, all you're doing is refreshing the page anyway. The whole point of ajax is to remove the need for full page reloads. If you're going to do that, you might as well use a normal postback, that way there's only one HTTP request needed, instead of two. Should be quicker and also reduces network overhead. What you've done is an anti-pattern really. Also the server returns a redirect which ajax can't follow, so it really makes no sense

Comment: I wanted to have in each step of the multi step form a serverside validation so because of that Im using ajax, I dont have much experience in ajax. But for what I understand and because in each step is necessary to have a serverside validation  in each step using a post request and use sessions should have a lower performance comparing with ajax and also it should be difficult to go back to a previous step. So maybe is better in each step store the data in jquery send to the validator and return if there is some error and then go to step 2 and do the same for the other steps.

Comment: Do you know what is necessary so the page is not refreshed in each step?

Comment: don't run window.reload() for a start! And then I guess your ajax request (when successful) would have to return the HTML needed for the next step, so you can replace the existing form with the new one for the next step (unless it's already hidden on the page somewhere?). Other than that you're basically going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I also have html for the other steps. But its not working, for now with the code as it is in the question when "go to step 2" is clicked the page is refreshed, the validation errors dont appear and the step 1 is the step that still appears.

Comment: ahh that's because your input button is a submit. So the ajax never fires, it just posts back as per default form behaviour. You have to suppress it as follows: `$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault();` . See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: BTW why are you doing all that complex processing of the form data in your click function / ajax call?  Try simply `data: custom_form.serialize()` in your ajax options. Unless your server expects a strange data format, that should work ok. But if you've been using the same server endpoint for a normal postback and it's worked, then just serialize() should achieve sending the data in the same format as the postback would.

Comment: Thanks, not it appears in the network tab 404 not found "http://store.test/event///payment/storeUserInfo". Dont understand why is using /// bars.

Comment: I guess that must be the output of `{{ route('products.storeUserInfo',null) }}` but I wouldn't know about that, I don't know what that syntax is from, it's not standard JS or PHP.

Comment: I changed as you said to just "var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);

                data: custom_form.serialize()

                $.ajax({". And then " data: data,". But now that 404 error dont appear but it seems that is because the ajax request with that code dont works.

Comment: I changed to "$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault();var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);data: custom_form.serialize()$.ajax({method: "POST",url: '{{ route('products.storeUserInfo',null) }}',contentType: false,processData: false,data: data,success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);},error: function (data) {var errors = data.responseJSON; $.each(errors['message'], function (index, value) { });} }); }); });".

Comment: You may need to remove contenttype:false and processData:false as well. That stuff is generally only needed if you're trying to upload files

Comment: Anyway what is "don't work"? You mean an error in the browser console or network tools? You can't just say don't work, I can't check your computer, you have to investigate a little bit.

Comment: I said dont work because adding this to the question code "$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault();" the ajax works, it showed that 404 error but if it show that error is because the ajax is working. But with the following code that 404 error dont appear which means that the ajax is not working.

Comment: "$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault();var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);data: custom_form.serialize()$.ajax({method: "POST",url: '{{ route('products.storeUserInfo',null) }}',data: data,success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);},error: function (data) {var errors = data.responseJSON; $.each(errors['message'], function (index, value) { });} }); }); });"

Comment: So if it's not replacing that with any other Ajax request that would mean the code is not executing. So either there's an error in the console or a logic error. So step through the JS with the debugger until you find it. That's what I mean by investigate